# Why am I getting this error: Unknown method 'AccountStandardController.Previous()'?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, pageblocktable, standardcontroller, pagination

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountTitlesController"> 
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Títulos" id="titles_list">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!newTitle}" onclick="this.form.target='_blank'" value="Novo título"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!titles}" var="title">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header"> Ação </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputLink value="{! URLFOR($Action.Titulo__c.Edit, title.Id) }">
                        Editar 
                    </apex:outputLink>
                    <apex:outputLink value="{! URLFOR($Action.Titulo__c.Delete, title.Id) }">
                        Excluir
                    </apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!title.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!title.NotaFiscal__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!title.NumeroParcela__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!title.Status__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!title.DataVencimento__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!title.ValorParcela__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!title.ValorTotalTitulo__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!title.NumDocSAP__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!title.LastModifiedDate}"/>
           </apex:pageBlockTable>
           <apex:commandLink action="{!Previous}" value="Previous Page"
            rendered="{!HasPrevious}"/>
            <apex:commandLink action="{!Next}" value="Next Page"
            rendered="{!HasNext}"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: the best resource on standard set controllers IMHO is [Visualforce in Practice Chapter 4](https://www.developerforce.com/guides/Visualforce_in_Practice.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

There is no [standard controller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_methods.htm) method previous() and your extension doesn't have a previous method either. Perhaps the cancel() method will work for you, but that depends on how your users get to your page.

Comment: Yep, it's the [StandardSetController](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardSetController_methods.htm) that contains methods for pagination.

Comment: @DerekF Thanks, I forgot about that one. It's been ages since I needed to use Visualforce

Comment: I just finished the "Visualforce Basics" module on trailhead and in "Use Standard List Controllers" unit teaches how to adding pagination just like that and there it works perfectly :(

Answer (score 1):

Add a recordSetVar and you'll get a working version:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="Accounts" extensions="AccountTitlesController">
```

You'll need to change your extension to accept a StandardSetController:

```
public AccountTitlesController(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
  // Do something with controller if you want to use it
}
```

All of the methods will then work as you've written your code.

---

To use a custom Standard Set Controller, which handles queries and pagination for you, just specify one in your Apex:

```
public ApexPages.StandardController titles { get; set; }
public MyClassName() { // This is a constructor
  titles = new ApexPages.StandardSetController([
    SELECT Fields FROM Object WHERE Conditions
  ]);
}
```

And then you can use that controller to navigate:

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!titles.Previous}" value="Previous Page"
        rendered="{!titles.HasPrevious}"/>
```

The apex:pageBlockTable needs to use the records method from the controller:

```
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!titles.records}" var="title">
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help!
I did the modifications just like you said and now I'm getting the error: /apex/vfAccountTitles @27,114 action="#{titles.Previous}": Unknown method 'List.Previous()'

Comment: @Rayssa Oh, of course. I forgot you'd have just a list. You need a ApexPages.StandardSetController. One second, I'll edit.